# Facebook JavaScript SDK example not navigating to login prompt

Tags: javascript, facebook

Using the full code example from Facebook Developer, I'm getting the following result in a popup:

```
Not Logged In: You are not logged in. Please login and try again.
```

I've even tried to simplify the process using the plugin configurator from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web to no avail.

I'm testing in localhost, so maybe that has something to do with it, but I have the localhost url configured in the `Site URL` section and the `Client OAuth Settings->Valid OAuth redirect URIs` section.

Here is my sample code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Facebook Login JavaScript Example</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version
                                    =v2.9&appId=150195524676348";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="medium"
     data-button-type="login_with" data-show-faces="false"
     data-auto-logout-link="true" data-use-continue-as="false"
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Facebook's documentation doesn't clearly explain a lot of things to me, all I really want to do is authenticate a user's account via Facebook and receive an access token.

Comment: you should do the login with the js sdk then, not with the login button. example: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved:

In my Facebook Developer app account, under Products, the Valid OAuth redirect URI wasn't set to the correct localhost port. After I corrected that, I started to receive the login prompt.